# Cómo encontrar la ubicación de un elemento en montos de listas y ordenarlos de forma tal que el monto donde esté sea el de la mitad

Tags: python, python-3.x, programación-funcional

escribo por este medio para obtener ayuda de cómo encontrar la ubicación de un elemento en montos de listas y ordenarlos de forma tal que el monto donde esté sea el de la mitad en otra lista. Es decir, tengo una lista con 3 sublistas y en cada sublistas hay 7 elementos, pero se escoge aleatoriamente uno de cualquiera de las 3 listas, debo de ubicar la lista en donde se encuentra el elemento y ordenar las listas en otra de forma tal que la lista en donde se encuentre el elemento escogido sea la segunda.

```py
[['AM', 'AG', 'AS', 'AP', 'AN', 'AK', 'AJ'],
 ['AE', 'AA', 'AI', 'AR', 'AQ', 'AC', 'AU'],
 ['AL', 'AD', 'AB', 'AT', 'AF', 'AH', 'AO']]
# ya se tiene anteriormente un elemento escogido al azar que es AE que está en el monto 2
#lo que necesito es crear una función en la cual encuentre en qué monto está 
#y que en una sola lista diferente ordene de tal forma que el monto donde esté esté en la mitad
```

El `return` debe ser

```
['AM', 'AG', 'AS', 'AP', 'AN', 'AK', 'AJ','AE', 'AA', 'AI', 'AR', 'AQ', 'AC', 'AU','AL', 'AD', 'AB', 'AT', 'AF', 'AH', 'AO']
```

Comment: no.. el elemento AE es un ejemplo, pero podría ser cualquier otro

Comment: lo siento no puedo entender lo que quieres, por el resultado que muestras, el contenido de las listas estan ordenadas, a que te refieres con "ordenarlos de forma tal que el monto donde esté sea el de la mitad en otra lista."?

Comment: Tranquilo, quiero una función que determine en dónde está un elemento que anteriormente ya se definió, puede ser por ejemplo AJ, este elemento está en la primera lista, entonces lo que quiero es que primero encuentre en qué lista está, si está en la primera o segunda o tercera, cuando ya detecte que está en la primera, lo que quiero que me haga en otra lista es colocar los montos de tal forma que en donde se encontro el elemento sea el monto de la mitad

Comment: Bueno lo entendi un poco mas pero aun no me queda claro lo de *"... tal forma que en donde se encontro el elemento sea el monto de la mitad"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una petición bastante extraña, tanto que temo quizás no haberla entendido bien. Lo que he entendido sería algo como:

```
datos = [
 ['AM', 'AG', 'AS', 'AP', 'AN', 'AK', 'AJ'],
 ['AE', 'AA', 'AI', 'AR', 'AQ', 'AC', 'AU'],
 ['AL', 'AD', 'AB', 'AT', 'AF', 'AH', 'AO']
]

nuevo = pon_en_medio(datos, "AM")
```

que resulte en:

```
['AE', 'AA', 'AI', 'AR', 'AQ', 'AC', 'AU', 
 'AM', 'AG', 'AS', 'AP', 'AN', 'AK', 'AJ', 
 'AL', 'AD', 'AB', 'AT', 'AF', 'AH', 'AO']
```

(He separado el resultado en tres líneas para poder comparar más fácilmente con los datos originales, pero el resultado sería en realidad una sola línea)

Es decir, el resultado contiene las tres sublistas originales, pero "aplanadas" en una sola lista, de modo que la sublista que contenía "AM" sería ahora la sublista central. Dentro de cada sublista el orden original se preserva.

Esto puede lograrse de muchas formas, pero la más breve y elegante que he encontrado es la siguiente:

```
def pon_en_medio(datos, elemento):
  result = sorted(datos, key=lambda monto: elemento in monto)
  result.insert(len(result)//2,result.pop(-1))
  return [e for monto in result for e in monto]
```

#### ¿Cómo funciona?

Primero tomo la lista original y reordeno en su interior sus sub-listas, usando `sorted()` al que le paso la misteriosa `key=lambda monto: elemento in monto`. Esto hace que `sorted()` ponga cada sublista en una posición que depende del resultado arrojado por esa `lambda`.

La lambda en cuestión retorna `False` si el elemento no está en esa sublista, o `True` si lo está. Por tanto retornará `False` dos veces y `True` solo una. Ya que numéricamente `False` es 0 y `True` es 1, todas las sublistas que han dado `False`  irán antes de las que hayan dado `True`. En resumen, **la lista elegida es colocada al final** de todas las sublistas.

Seguidamente la quito del final y la pongo en el medio, con la línea:

```
result.insert(len(result)//2, result.pop(-1))
```

`result.pop()` elimina y retorna un elemento de la lista `result`, en este caso el elemento -1 que es el último monto. Ese monto es insertado en el centro gracias al `len(result)//2`.

En este momento tenemos los tres montos en el orden deseado, es decir, el monto central es el que tiene el elemento elegido. Pero `result` sigue siendo una lista de sublistas. La última línea:

```
  return [e for monto in result for e in monto]
```

sirve para "aplanar" el resultado, es decir, convertirlo en una lista de elementos en vez de una lista de sublistas. Para ello usa una *comprensión de listas* con dos bucles anidados.

Comment: abulafia, te agradezco bastante, me aclaro mucho el camino,  qué me recomiendas para mejorar en mis habilidades en programación?. Que estés muy bien. De nuevo te agradezco.

Comment: Hola @Graciela. No me des las gracias, pero si quieres puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Para mejorar te recomiendo que leas mucho, y no solo libros, cursos o tutoriales, sino también programas de otros (repositorios git, etc.) Por ejemplo, aquí en StackOverflow, puedes leer de vez en cuando alguna pregunta y sus respuestas. Se aprenden cosas nuevas que nunca se te ocurrirían. Y también intentando participar para responder te fuerzas a pensar en problemas que no son tuyos, pero cuyas soluciones podrán serte útiles en algún momento.

Comment: creo ya acepte la respuesta, soy nueva en stackoverflow espero haber aceptado la respuesta correctamente.

Comment: Todo bien, gracias!

Comment: Ha! yo pense que no era eso, casi le doy esa respuesta, pero no estaba seguro

Comment: @abulafia Me disculpa de nuevo molestarlo pero me podrías orientar en este mismo ejercicio cómo puedo repetir ese proceso 3 veces y que cada vez actualice la lista en la cual debe hacer el proceso por la resultante en nuevo?